# SSDT Unit Testing. Move scripts in files

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools, vs-unit-testing-framework

I would like know if it's possible to move testing scripts from resource file to external separate files. This would facilitate the development process. You could use not only VS (different IDE or SSMS, etc) to just check/change/develop them without even starting SSDT. Plus this would help keep some history in version control system.

Currently, I can change a *SqlDatabaseTestClass* class to reload the scripts from files, but this doesn't affect unit tests SSDT Editor/Designer in VS. So, it continues generating and loading code from resx. I wanted to change/create class that is responsible for SQL Unit Test SSDT Designer in VisualStudio, but can't find the assembly to inherit from the class.

Maybe there is anything else, that is much simpler to implement

Comment: By the way, I tried the naive technique of using the SQLCMD `:r filename` command to include a real file in a pre-test script, but that didn't work at all. I guess those scripts do not use SQLCMD.

Answer (score 1):

An approach that is independent of VS/SSMS is to use the open source [tSQLt unit testing framework](http://tsqlt.org). Tests (and the framework itself) are saved in the development database as SQL objects.

Comment: Thanks David, we knew about *tSQLt*, but I think we have found a balance. Now, next to *SSDT Unit Testing* project we also have a *Database Project* with all physical sql files of SPs (that represent tests) that we easily push/update through SSDT tools. In *SSDT Unit Testing* project we just call those SPs as separate tests. It became easier to manage those now.

Comment: That's not really an answer to the question. The OP didn't ask: are there other test frameworks I could use instead.